# Why does the output changes when i change the value of variables?

Tags: c, cpu, scheduling

This is my code for FCFS CPU scheduling algorithm. When I replace j=1 then the output changes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    char pn[10][10],t[10];
    int arr[10],bur[10],star[10],finish[10],tat[10],wt[10],i,j,n,temp;
    int totwt=0,tottat=0;
//clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number of processes:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the ProcessName, Arrival Time& Burst Time:");
        scanf("%s%d%d",&pn[i],&arr[i],&bur[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]<arr[j])
            {
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
                temp=bur[i];
                bur[i]=bur[j];
                bur[j]=temp;
                strcpy(t,pn[i]);
                strcpy(pn[i],pn[j]);
                strcpy(pn[j],t);
            }

        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            star[i]=arr[i];
        else
            star[i]=finish[i-1];
        wt[i]=star[i]-arr[i];
        finish[i]=star[i]+bur[i];
        tat[i]=finish[i]-arr[i];
    }
    printf("\nPName Arrtime Burtime WaitTime Start TAT Finish");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%3d\t%6d\t%6d",pn[i],arr[i],bur[i],wt[i],star[i],tat[i],finish[i]);
        totwt+=wt[i];
        tottat+=tat[i];
    }
    printf("\nAverage Waiting time:%f",(float)totwt/n);
    printf("\nAverage Turn Around Time:%f",(float)tottat/n);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Problem Line:

```
for(j=0; j<n; j++)
```

According to me, the output should not change when I change j=1. As the condition `arr[i]<arr[j]`  is going to be false anyway and that step will be skipped.
You can run the program yourselves and see the output with and without the changed value.

Comment: Probably because of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Parallel arrays suggest the use of `struct`.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to dig into that area to see what's going on?

Comment: You should remove the cpu tag from the question.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `usage` or `content` (of better, both)`  names like `pn`, `t`, `bur`, `tat` `wt`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input/format specifiers '%s' and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This will avoid any buffer overflow, which would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when inputting values from the an external source, especially from the user, always validate the value.  For instance, what if the use entered 10 (or 100 or 1000) for the 'number of processes'?

Comment: regarding: `printf("Enter the ProcessName, Arrival Time& Burst Time:");
        scanf("%s%d%d",&pn[i],&arr[i],&bur[i]);`  How can a 'time' be a single 'int'?

Comment: regarding the last two calls to `printf()` the 'format strings' should end with '\n so the data is immediately output to the terminal rather than waiting until (either) the `getch()` is executed or the program exits.

Comment: suggest using the `VLA` feature (Variable Length Arrays) by declaring 'n', using 'scanf()' to input 'n', then using 'n' as the sizing on each of the arrays  (I suggest still checking that 'n' is >0)

Comment: to obtain a proper sort, this line: `for(j=0; j<n; j++)` should be: `for(j=i; j<n; j++)`` rather than starting at 0 for each iteration of the outer `for()` loop

Answer (score 1):

The first and most severe problem is

```
scanf("%s%d%d",&pn[i],&arr[i],&bur[i]);
```

note that you are passing a pointer to the next character at each call, this code is also non-deterministic because the value of `n` is not restricted at all, and there are values of `n` that would cause a buffer overflow but your code does not check for that.

Also, since

```
scanf("%s%d%d",&pn[i],&arr[i],&bur[i]);
```

has no restriction on the number of characters that would be read and stored as far as `pn[9]`, then you will mostly for sure overflow `pn`.

You probably wanted something different, for instance

```
char pn[10][10];
```

and

```
scanf("%s%d%d", pn[i], &arr[i], &bur[i]);
//             ^ note that you don't need the & for this
```

You probably have confused `char` with *string*, a `char` type is just an integral type and a *string* *is*/*can be* made of values of `char` type.

So to answer the title of your question:

- The code is surely invoking undefined behavior, such behavior is non-deterministic and depends on things that you can't actually control, so changing some values will probably change the output.

Now you might ask *So how do I fix this?*

Well,

1. Check that `scanf()` actually did initialze `n` *and*/*or* explicitly initialize `n` to a value that you know that doesn't make sense like `-1`, check after `scanf()` that your value fits the requirements, i.e. that it will not cause a buffer overflow and that it was input by the user.
2. Use a more appropriate storage for your strings, and learn what strings really are so that you can manipulate them correctly. This is a difficult topic in [c](/questions/tagged/c) programming, so do all the research you can and unless you feel that you have mastered it, don't try to use strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Comment: You will not be able to do much in C without using char arrays (with a NUL terminator)  So suggest getting help when needed.

Answer (score -1):

> According to me, the output should not change when I change j=1. As
>   the condition arr[i]    < arr[j] is going to be false anyway and that step
>   will be skipped.

No. The condition is only guaranteed to be false when i = j. Yes, in the first iteration of the outer loop, i = j = 0. But in all other iterations of the outer loop, it makes a difference whether j starts at 0 or 1. For example, in the second iteration of the outer loop, i = 1. If j = 0, the condition may be true. On the other hand, starting with j = 1 skips the iteration where j = 0, potentially producing different results. This applies to all other iterations of the outer loop.

The issue you're facing has nothing to do with undefined behavior.